# Request Mappings, leave out specific cases instead of catching all

Tags: spring, swagger, request-mapping

### Introduction

We have has created a request mapping as the following:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/{project}/{resource}/{language}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Resource> get(
        @PathVariable String project, 
        @PathVariable String resource, 
        @PathVariable String language) throws IOException {
```

We could change the path and add a prefix in order to avoid issues but this has been decided as unwanted.

```
path = "/generateReport/{project}/{resource}/{language}"
```

Unfortunately, this current mapping is creating problems with swagger-ui.html. 
When we call it from: http://localhost:8023/swagger-ui.html , the page is blank because all the requests that follow the format `a/b/c` are hijacked.

Examples:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/springfox.css?v=2.8.0-SNAPSHOT" >
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/swagger-ui.css?v=2.8.0-SNAPSHOT" >
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/favicon-32x32.png?v=2.8.0-SNAPSHOT" sizes="32x32" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/favicon-16x16.png?v=2.8.0-SNAPSHOT" sizes="16x16" />
```

And

```
<script src="webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/swagger-ui-bundle.js?v=2.8.0-SNAPSHOT"> </script>
<script src="webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js?v=2.8.0-SNAPSHOT"> </script>
<script src="webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/springfox.js?v=2.8.0-SNAPSHOT"> </script>
```

### Question

So how do i deal with this? Is there a way to specify that requests starting with `webjars` should be re-directed elsewhere?

I tried using the `consumes` keyword, and this works in terms of the client (though I don't like using the content-type like this).

`consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` .

Unfortunately, now I am getting the following when I try to access swagger-ui.html :

```
DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type '' not supported
```

The HTML is being generated for swagger-ui.html, but all the resources it needs cannot be loaded.

**Any ideas?**

### Update

I found a work around using path variables and regular expressions:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/{project:^(?!webjars).+}/{resource}/{language}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Resource> get(
        @PathVariable String project, 
        @PathVariable String resource, 
        @PathVariable String language) throws IOException {
```

**However, new answers are still appreciated as I don''t like this 100%**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around using path variables and regular expressions:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/{project:^(?!webjars).+}/{resource}/{language}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Resource> get(
        @PathVariable String project, 
        @PathVariable String resource, 
        @PathVariable String language) throws IOException {
```

However, new answers are still appreciated!